# Spoof network gateway

Tags: linux, lan, arp, spoofing

If I said I wanted to spoof gateway to make device 2 on LAN look like gateway when router/modem by att is really gateway, technically be man in the middle? So all devices traffic on LAN would go to device 2 then out of router to internet.

Reason I ask is because I have a spare x86 device with  one nic and ClearOS . I want to use their gateway packages like gateway antivirus, instrution detection and content filter . The only way I can think of doing this is a.) buy another nic and make it the router/default gateway or b.) use one nic and use the `arpspoof` command to poison other device in devices arp tables. I know this arpspoofing is used for MITM . Yet I'm just using to to trick all devices that clearos device is the default gateway and then forward it to the actual gateway/server(ATT).

Besides if it's mitm, if I do this to my own network is it something bad and should stay clear? I'm not against buying another box, just want to see if I can use one nic.

Comment: While it may be possible with arpspoof, I imagine it will be quite glitchy. I'd recommend getting a second nic or seeing if there are other solutions.

Comment: It sounds like I just need to turn off the DHCP on the ATT gateway and make the device with one nic the DHCP Server. Instead of playing man in the middle. The issue is this device is a manage device that can be "plug and play" ready in order for people that have no clue what DHCP server . Turning DHCP off on the modem/router side isn't as easy for non tech people, so thats why I was looking for more of man in middle. Thanks again

Comment: I think this is now the 4th time or so something similar has been asked in the last few weeks. No, arpspoof won't work 100% reliably all the time. Do a proper setup, like Benjamin Jones described if you don't have second NIC.

Comment: Yes but there is no reason to why it wouldn't work.  arpspoof works off layer 2 right? There are applications that provide that layer 7(application) interaction to gain insight for MITM. I don't see the difference. With tcpdump on the spoofing device(that is spoofing the gateway)  I have proved I see traffic going through 1st before the gateway and out to internet. I can capture all those packets that a transverse. So why couldn't I setup a application such as a web proxy(squid) or even a OS such a clear-OS? Yes this doesn't work, but I don't see why not? Thats what I am trying to figure out?